# Creating Civil 3D Alignment in .Net throws "Alignment ID is invalid" error

Tags: c#, .net, autodesk, ifc

I am developing an IFC (Industry Foundation Classes) Import/Export Add-In for Civil 3D, which I will publish as open source later this month). The export function works completely fine already. However, I still don't quite understand how to create objects in Civil 3D using .NET. My add-in is written in C#.

I tried the following, which is a official Autodesk example:

```
// Uses an existing Alignment Style named "Basic" and Label Set Style named "All Labels" (for example, from
// the _AutoCAD Civil 3D (Imperial) NCS.dwt template.  This call will fail if the named styles
// don't exist. 
// Uses layer 0, and no site (ObjectId.Null)
ObjectId testAlignmentID = Alignment.Create(doc, "New Alignment", ObjectId.Null, "0", "Basic", "All Labels");
```

source: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Civil3D-DevGuide/files/GUID-F620DF41-7DF3-450F-8C2A-A92DEB1F9E9E-htm.html

However, whenever I try to run my code, I get the following error message: *"Invalid Alignment ID."*. My code looks like the following:

```
var civilDatabase = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
var civilDocument = CivilApplication.ActiveDocument;
using (Transaction civilTransactionManager =
        civilDatabase.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
   ObjectId civilAlignment = Alignment.Create(civilDocument, "MyName", "" , "0", "Basic", "All Labels");
```

I also tried to replace  the *""* that gives the site for the Alignment with *null* or *ObjectID.Null*, both does not work and replacing it with *ObjectID.Null* does even prevent me from compiling.

Anyone knows where that error comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [Alignment methods](http://docs.autodesk.com/CIV3D/2015/ENU/API_Reference_Guide/html/a707421b-0b28-9b53-fb09-1205e993ef5b.htm), more specifically the [following](http://docs.autodesk.com/CIV3D/2015/ENU/API_Reference_Guide/html/858c3c00-a967-985f-8c9a-750447e4c9e7.htm) overload:

```
public static ObjectId Create(
    CivilDocument document,
    string alignmentName,
    string siteName,
    string layerName,
    string styleName,
    string labelSetName
)
```

It says:

> System.ArgumentException
>
> The name of the drawing, layer, style, labelSet or site is invalid. The name of the alignment already exists.

So it seems some of the names are not correct. For a more robust approach, you may list the styles and get a name or objectId from there. For a siteless alignment, you can pass `string.empty` as `siteName` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer Augusto! I thought so too, because the error did point into that direction.

Hoever, Jeff from Autodesk was able to help me and provided a working solution. Apparently this was part of a bigger problem with me main code, or the way I approached things. 
With Jeff's solution provided in the following post, I got everything to work:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-civil-3d-customization/creating-alignment-throws-quot-alignment-id-is-invalid-quot/m-p/7302387/highlight/false#M13831